# 3D Plot: Number of Roots in x of a polynomial in x, a, b and c

Tags: plotting, polynomials

I have a polynomial in four variables x,a,b and c. The number of roots of the polynomial in x depends of the choice of a, b and c. I would like to have a 3D-Plot with a, b and c on the axes, while the number of roots >0 at a point (a,b,c) is symbolized by different colours.

The most important to me is to see where exactly the transitions are.

I think I need `CountRoots[Polynom,{x,0,Infinity}]`, but as I am new to Mathematica I can't figure out how to do this. Thanks a lot for your help!

The function is

```
-a b (1 + 
    c) (a^8 (1 + c)^4 (6 - 56 c + 68 c^2 - 56 c^3 + 6 c^4 + 
       3 b (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c)) + 
    a^7 b (1 + c)^4 (9 b (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c) - 256 c (1 - c + c^2)) + 
    3 a^6 b^3 (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c)^5 - 
    8 a^6 b^2 (1 + c)^4 (15 + 52 c - 22 c^2 + 52 c^3 + 15 c^4) - 
    15 a^5 b^4 (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c)^5 - 
    128 a^5 b^3 (1 + c)^4 (3 + 2 c + 4 c^2 + 2 c^3 + 3 c^4) + 
    3 a^3 b^6 (1 + c) (-1 + c^2)^4 - 
    128 a^3 b^5 (1 + c)^4 (3 + 2 c + 4 c^2 + 2 c^3 + 3 c^4) - 
    15 a^4 b^5 (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c)^5 - 
    20 a^4 b^4 (1 + c)^4 (27 + 4 c + 50 c^2 + 4 c^3 + 27 c^4) + 
    3 a b^8 (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c)^5 - 
    256 a b^7 c (1 + c)^4 (1 - c + c^2) + 
    9 a^2 b^7 (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c)^5 - 
    8 a^2 b^6 (1 + c)^4 (15 + 52 c - 22 c^2 + 52 c^3 + 15 c^4) + 
    2 b^8 (1 + c)^4 (3 - 28 c + 34 c^2 - 28 c^3 + 3 c^4)) - 
 a b (1 + c) (21 a^6 b (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c)^3 - 
    30 a^6 (1 + c)^2 (5 - 12 c + 30 c^2 - 12 c^3 + 5 c^4) + 
    21 a^5 b^2 (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c)^3 - 
    60 a^5 b (1 + c)^2 (7 - 4 c + 42 c^2 - 4 c^3 + 7 c^4) - 
    42 a^3 b^4 (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c)^3 - 
    120 a^3 b^3 (1 + c) (1 + 37 c + 42 c^2 + 42 c^3 + 37 c^4 + c^5) - 
    42 a^4 b^3 (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c)^3 - 
    30 a^4 b^2 (1 + c)^2 (11 + 76 c + 66 c^2 + 76 c^3 + 11 c^4) + 
    21 a b^6 (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c)^3 - 
    60 a b^5 (1 + c)^2 (7 - 4 c + 42 c^2 - 4 c^3 + 7 c^4) + 
    21 a^2 b^5 (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c)^3 - 
    30 a^2 b^4 (1 + c)^2 (11 + 76 c + 66 c^2 + 76 c^3 + 11 c^4) - 
    30 b^6 (1 + c)^2 (5 - 12 c + 30 c^2 - 12 c^3 + 5 c^4)) x - 
 a b (1 + c) (54 a^3 b^2 (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c) - 
    168 a^3 b (1 + c) (1 + 11 c + 11 c^2 + c^3) - 
    54 a^4 b (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c) - 
    6 a^4 (29 - 4 c + 286 c^2 - 4 c^3 + 29 c^4) - 
    54 a b^4 (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c) - 
    168 a b^3 (1 + c)^2 (1 + 10 c + c^2) + 
    54 a^2 b^3 (-1 + c)^4 (1 + c) + 
    12 a^2 b^2 (1 - 340 c - 330 c^2 - 340 c^3 + c^4) - 
    6 b^4 (29 - 4 c + 286 c^2 - 4 c^3 + 29 c^4)) x^2 - 
 a b (1 + c) (-20 a b (9 + 50 c + 9 c^2) - 
    10 a^2 (9 + 50 c + 9 c^2) - 10 b^2 (9 + 50 c + 9 c^2)) x^3 + 
 72 a b (1 + c) x^4
```

Comment: Can you give us the polynomial explicitly..?

Comment: I did not at first because it is really ugly.

Comment: "Number of roots" as in "number of real roots"? A cubic always has three roots, for instance...

Comment: Number of real roots >0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Defining your polynomial as

```
p[x_, a_, b_, c_] := the formula
```

I'd do this :

```
Manipulate[ CountRoots[ p[x, a, b, c], {x, 0, Infinity}],
            {a, -100, 100}, {b, -100, 100}, {c, -100, 100}]
```

[image]

If a plot is needed one can proceed this way :

```
ListContourPlot3D[ Table[ CountRoots[ p[x, a, b, c], {x, 0, Infinity}],
                          {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}, {c, -10, 10} ], Contours -> 3,
                   Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> {Red, Yellow, Lighter @ Blue},              
                   DataRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

[image]

Another way (the most expensive) is to make use of `RegionPlot3D`. Here are `3d` regions where a given polynomial has respectively : at least `1`, `2` and `3` roots for `x > 0`

```
GraphicsRow[ 
    Table[ RegionPlot3D[ CountRoots[ p[x, a, b, c], {x, 0, Infinity}] >= k,
                         {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}, {c, -10, 10}, 
                         PlotStyle -> Directive[ Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]],
           {k,  3}]]
```

[image]

One can see that for for higher `k` we need a better resolution, nevertheless it appears very expensive to compute regions using higher `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` options.

```
 RegionPlot3D[ CountRoots[ p[x, a, b, c], {x, 0, Infinity}] >= 2, 
               {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}, {c, -10, 10}, 
               PlotStyle -> Directive[ Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]],
               PlotPoints -> 40, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is great for me to get to know the function! But I really need a plot I can print on paper.

Comment: @Apatura I updated my answer with a `ListContourPlot3D`.

Comment: Cute plot work!

Comment: @Artes: RegionPlot does exactly what I want, thank you very much! Unfortunately, when I try a different function, it gives back a strange error. What is wrong with `RegionPlot3D[
 CountRoots[\[Sigma]q33[\[Omega], V1, V2, V3], {\[Omega], 0, 
    Infinity}] == 1, {V1, 0, 10}, {V2, 0, 10}, {V3, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.5]], Mesh -> None]` if \[Sigma]q33 is a polynomial in omega, Exp[-V1],Exp[-V2] and Exp[-V3]?

Comment: @Apatura You are welcome. Note that when I set `PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 3` it took more than 5 minutes to evaluate. If you have an error most likely it is because of a wrong definition of your function `\[Sigma]q33`. Look carefully at the documentation of `RegionPlot3D`.

Comment: @Apatura If you defined that function just like I had done with `p` you wouldn't get any errors. Try the same with `p`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's one approach.  Generate data (for a simple polynomial):

```
data = Table[CountRoots[a*x^2 + b*x + c, x],
  {a, -5, 5, 0.5}, {b, -5, 5, 0.5}, {c, -5, 5, 0.5}];
```

Then we'll display a collection of  `Cuboids` with `Opacity` based on this data.

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[],
  MapIndexed[Which[
    # == 0, {Red, Cuboid[#2, #2 + {1, 1, 1}]},
    # == 1, {White, Cuboid[#2, #2 + {1, 1, 1}]},
    # == 2, {Blue, Cuboid[#2, #2 + {1, 1, 1}]}] &,
  data, {3}]}]
```

[image]

Now it appears to turn out, that your more complicated functions all have zero, one, or two roots.  Changing the `With` statement accordingly, we get the following.

[image]

You might also look into `CUDAVolumetricRender`, if you have a good NVidia graphics card.

Comment: Might also be a good idea to generate a separate plot for the different root counts...

Comment: @J.M. I'm not sure I follow - that image is based on root counts.  I turns out that all polynomials in that family have on zero, two, or four roots - hence, the three colors.

Comment: Hmm, I thought you were doing something like `ContourPlot3D[(* root-counting function *), {a, ...}, {b, ...}, {c, ...}, Contours -> {0, 2, 4}]`...

Comment: I'd have used `Switch[]` instead of `Which[]` myself... something like `{Switch[#, 0, Red, 1, White, 2, Blue], Cuboid[#2, #2 + {1, 1, 1}]} &`.

Comment: @MarkMcClure will you please explain a bit how to use `CUDAVolumetricRender` in this context?

Comment: @PlatoManiac No, I actually can't. `CUDAVolumetricRender` is designed specifically to render 3D data, like we have here. It depends on a high end NVidia GPU, however, which I don't have. I was acutally hoping that someone else might take a stab at it.

Comment: I guess the new `Image3D[]` could also be used for this.