# Count and plot the number of solutions in an interval

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have equations depending on one or more parameters and I want to find and plot  regions in the parameter space in which there is a specific number of solutions.

For definiteness let's consider a simple case

```
-3 + 3 mu2 - 6 q mu2 - 8 q^3 mu4 + 4 q^4 mu4 + q^2 (3 mu2+ 4 mu4) == 0
```

where I want to find and/or plot regions in the space `(mu2,mu4)` in which the equation has `0, 1,...,4` solutions with `0 < q < 1`.

Note that I want to use the same method also for non-polynomial equations (and possibly systems of equations).

Comment: For the polynomial case, you might find Kharitonov's theorem useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kharitonov%27s_theorem

Comment: You've seen `CountRoots[]`?

Comment: @bills Thanks, very interesting

Comment: @Fabrizio You can of course define `cr[mu2_, mu4_] := 
 CountRoots[-3 + 3 mu2 - 6 q mu2 - 8 q^3 mu4 + 4 q^4 mu4 + 
   q^2 (3 mu2 + 4 mu4), {q, 0, 1}]`, i.e. it counts the number of roots for `q` in the range `[0, 1]`.

Comment: @Fabrizio If your equation is not an adequate example could you provide another one you want to deal with? Otherwise your question cannnot be answered in a more reliable way.

Comment: @Artes I think that the answer is explanatory enough. I haven't examples that require a different solution, but whose solution is general enough to be really useful. If you have one, let me know.

Comment: @Fabrizio My answer provides a way to go with your example, but if one deals with transcendental equations it might be a problem to be solved on case by case basis. See e.g. this post [When does the real part of Zeta vanish on the critical line?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/when-does-the-real-part-of-zeta-vanish-on-the-critical-line/34607#34607) to deal with a more difficult case of a transcendental equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CountRoots` is an appropriate function. It may work also with more general functions than polynomials. Two or more-variable polynomials may have infinitely many roots in a compact region, e.g. this one: $\;p(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1 \quad$ has infinitely many roots (continuum) on the unit sphere. In such cases `CountRoots` cannot give an adequate answer since it may count only a finite number of roots (of univariate polynomials, but we can always restrict many-variable functions to one variable) in an adequate domain (it may be a rectangle in the complex plane).

For the problem at hand let's define:

```
cr[mu2_, mu4_] := CountRoots[-3 + 3 mu2 - 6 q mu2 - 8 q^3 mu4 + 4 q^4 mu4 + 
                              q^2 (3 mu2 + 4 mu4), q]
```

To get an idea where you should look for interesting regions `Manipulate` can serve reasonably :

```
Manipulate[ cr[mu2, mu4], {mu2, -100, 100}, {mu4, -100, 100}]
```

To visualize spatial dependence of the `cr` function we can make use of `ListPlot3D` having an array of its values :

```
ar = Array[{#1, #2, cr[#1, #2]} &, {200, 200}, {{-30, 30}, {-30, 30}}];
ListPlot3D[ Flatten[ar, 1], Mesh -> None,
            ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Darker @ Hue[1/4 z]]]
```

[image]

Where we can see the jumps on the plot we might expect `1` and `3` roots of the polynomial.

For more complete discussion of the issue this question needs better examples and more precise formulation. One can proceed further with `Reduce` and `Solve` etc. Solving equation with `Solve` it might be more handy when there are finite number of solutions (because of the output in terms of replacement rules). On the other hand there might be many subtleties and one can proceed on the case by case basis (see e.g. [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768) where one can simply count roots e.g. with `Length`). For a bit more interesting example of a polynomial equation see this question : 3D Plot: [Number of Roots in x of a polynomial in x, a, b and c](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10713/3d-plot-number-of-roots-in-x-of-a-polynomial-in-x-a-b-and-c).

Comment: The boundary of those regions is where the discriminant wrt q vanishes 9which gives another approach to finding regions for different real-root counts.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment of J.M., it's possible to use `CountRoots[]`, for the case in the question one possible solution is

```
myF[Q_, mu2_, mu4_] := -3 + 3 mu2 q^2 + 4 mu4 q^4 - 6 mu2 q Q - 8 mu4 q^3 Q + 3 mu2 Q^2 + 4 mu4 q^2 Q^2

myCR[Q_, mu2_, mu4_] := CountRoots[myF[Q, mu2, mu4], {q, 0, Q}]

ContourPlot[myCR[myQ, mu2, mu4], {mu4, 0, 15}, {mu2, 0, 2}, 
ImageSize -> 300, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
ContourLabels -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> None, 
Contours -> {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

obtaining

[image]

Although the question is still open for the case of non-polynomial equations.

Comment: If you provided certain non-polynomial equations, then it would be possible to answer in a constructive way or justify why that wouldn't be accessible. I mean that basically one can discuss the issue with a problem at hand not in general.