# When does the real part of Zeta vanish on the critical line?

Tags: equation-solving, complex, special-functions

This seems to be a quite a simple problem but I cannot make it work.
I am trying to find all values within a given range for which the real part of the `Zeta` function vanishes on the line: $\;z=\frac{1}{2} + i\;y$.

Given the following plot:

```
Plot[Re[ Zeta[ 1/2 + I t]], {t, 14, 14.6}]
```

[image: real part of Riemann zeta over the critical line]

I would like to get the values: $14.13...\;, 14.5....$.

Comment: Closely related [Why do these two different zetas produce the same value?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25430/why-do-these-two-different-zetas-produce-the-same-value). You can use `Solve[Zeta[x] == -(1/12) && Abs[x] < 20, x]`.

Comment: `FindRoot[Re[Zeta[1/2 + I t]], {t, #}] & /@ {14, 14.5}` yields `{{t -> 14.1347}, {t -> 14.5179}}`. By the way your question is still far from being clear.

Comment: @ Artes - thank you - this is what I was after!

Comment: @Artes, FindRoot[Re[Zeta[1/2 + I t]], {t, #}] & /@ {14, 25} yields {{t -> 14.1347}, {t -> 25.0109}} - how would I get it to output all values within that range?

Comment: Are you looking for roots of `Re@Zeta[1/2 + I t]`? `Re@Zeta[x]` can intersect `s=1/2 + iy` only when `y == 0`.

Comment: `FindRoot[Re[Zeta[1/2 + I t]], {t, #}] & /@ Range[14, 25]`

Comment: @ Artes - many thanks - apologies for lack of clarity!

Comment: @ Artes, For some reason, that code gives loads of duplicates ... it is not much of a problem, but do you know why this is happening?

Comment: We find numericall solutions with `FindRoot` nonetheless you can get rid of them using appropriate functionality. This gives you a simple approach `Im[ZetaZero[#] & /@ Range[3] // N]`.

Comment: Ok - Many thanks - would have done it in excel!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When symbolically solving transcendental equations, one should appropriately use `Solve` or `Reduce` with adequate logical combinations of equations, inequalities, domain specifications, etc. to get desired results. There are limitations for certain types of equations involving transcendental functions, see e.g. [Transcendental Roots](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/newin7/content/TranscendentalRoots/). Here is an example which doesn't work in *Mathematica 9*:

```
Reduce[ Re[Zeta[x]] == 0 && 14 < Im[x] < 15 && Re[x] == 1/2, x]
```

Namely, it cannot find roots of the real part of `Zeta`; nonetheless, we can find symbolic zeros of the Riemann `Zeta` function:

```
Solve[Zeta[x] == 0 && 0 < Im[x] < 25 && Re[x] == 1/2, x]
```

> ```
> {{x -> ZetaZero[1]}, {x -> ZetaZero[2]}}
> ```

Let's use `Reduce` in another way:

```
Reduce[ Zeta[ 1/2 + I t] == 0 && 0 <= t <= 250, t]
```

> ```
> C[1] ∈ Integers && 1 <= C[1] <= 108 && t == -(1/2) I (-1 + 2 ZetaZero[C[1]])
> ```

Here, we provide plot of the real and imaginary part of `Zeta` on the critical line, in the range `0 < t < 50`:

```
Plot[ Table[ h[ Zeta[ 1/2 + I t]], {h, {Re, Im}}], {t, 0, 50}, 
      Evaluated -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/4, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.007], Point[{Im@ZetaZero[#], 0} & /@ Range[10]]}, 
      ImageSize -> 800, PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {Left, Top}]]
```

[image: plot]

The function `ZetaZero` is very useful, since one can evaluate its numerical values up to `10^7`-th zero (on the other hand, we know there are infinitely many `Zeta` zeros on the critical line), then one should work with e.g. `FindRoot` yielding numerical results.

```
ZetaZero /@ {1, 2, 10^7} // Im // N
```

> ```
> {14.1347, 21.022, 4.99238*10^6}
> ```

If we are satisfied with numerical values only, we can use `FindRoot` to get zeros of the real part of `Zeta` between `14` and `15`:

```
FindRoot[ Re[ Zeta[ 1/2 + I t]], {t, #, 14, 15}]& /@ {14, 14.5}
```

> ```
> {{t -> 14.1347}, {t -> 14.5179}}
> ```

```
Zeta[1/2 + I t] /. % // Chop
```

> ```
> {0, 0. + 0.31227 I}
> ```

Working with `FindRoot`, it should be useful to localize approximately starting values with `ContourPlot` like e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25430/why-do-these-two-different-zetas-produce-the-same-value/25439#25439).

Answer (score 4):

We can use [`FindAllCrossings[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5666) to find the roots of $\Re\left(\zeta\left(\frac12+i t\right)\right)$ like so:

```
FindAllCrossings[Re[Zeta[1/2 + I t]], {t, 10, 30}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
   {14.134725141734693790, 14.517919628262233651, 20.654044969367919453,
    21.022039638771554993, 25.010857580145688763, 25.491508214625488621,
    29.738510300151580038}
```

This is of course a superset of the zeroes of $\zeta(s)$, as we can see:

```
N[Im[ZetaZero[Range[7]]], 20]
   {14.134725141734693790, 21.022039638771554993, 25.010857580145688763,
    30.424876125859513210, 32.935061587739189691, 37.586178158825671257,
    40.918719012147495187}
```

where for instance we see that $s_2\approx\frac12+14.5179196i$ is a zero of $\Re(\zeta(s))$, but not a zero of $\zeta(s)$.

---

**Digression**

Back in the day, before `ZetaZero[]` became built-in, I also used `FindAllCrossings[]` to find the zeroes of $\zeta(s)$ on the critical line. The function I used for this is the associated [Riemann-Siegel function $Z(t)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-SiegelFunctions.html). Here is how I used it:

```
FindAllCrossings[RiemannSiegelZ[t], {t, 10, 42}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

where the results are virtually the same as that of `N[Im[ZetaZero[Range[7]]], 20]`.

The approach is still useful for the more complicated example of the [Ramanujan-Dirichlet series $\mathcal{f}(s)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TauDirichletSeries.html), which is built-in as `RamanujanTauL[]`. In this scenario, the critical line is at $\Re(s)=6$ instead of $\Re(s)=\frac12$ for $\zeta(s)$. $\mathcal{f}(s)$ also has an associated $Z$ function, built-in as `RamanujanTauZ[]`, that is useful in finding the zeroes of $\mathcal{f}(s)$ on its critical line (see also [Keiper's](http://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/jerry-keiper/) [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-96-00734-X) for more details):

```
(* this takes a long time; this function is harder than RiemannSiegelZ[]! *)
FindAllCrossings[RamanujanTauZ[t], {t, 8, 20}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // Quiet
   {9.2223793999211025235, 13.907549861392134406, 17.442776978234473314,
    19.656513141954961000}
```

Verify:

```
RamanujanTauL[6 + I %] // Chop
   {0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Comment: Great - that's a new one on me :)