# Solving Inequalities with Gamma Function

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I am wondering why *Mathematica* outputs that the following system "cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce".

$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+n)}{n-1}<\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+k)}{k-1}$

with $k, n \in N$. I used the command

```
Reduce[Gamma[1/2 + n]/(-1 + n) < Gamma[1/2 + k]/(-1 + k) && k > 1 && n > 1, {n}, Integers]
```

and tried unsuccessfully to solve for $k$ and $n$.

I suppose, I do something improper and *Mathematica* is capable to solve those kind of inequalities. So, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6):

First let's start with a symbolic approach in the reals. 
This is a general issue arrising in systems of equations and/or inequalities involving the Euler gamma function and a simple univariate polynomial, e.g.:

```
Reduce[ Gamma[x] == (-1 + x)^6 && x > 1, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. >>
> ```

we can remedy this problem by adding an upper bound, e.g. let's supplement the system with `100 > x`:

```
Reduce[ Gamma[x] == (-1 + x)^6 && 100 > x > 1, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> Reduce::incs: Warning: Reduce was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete. >>
>
> x == 2 || 
> x == Root[{1 - Gamma[#1] - 6 #1 + 15 #1^2 - 20 #1^3 + 15 #1^4 - 6 #1^5 + #1^6 &,
>            10.23754139578609138335400426041}]
> ```

Let's plot the function appearing in the original question, i.e. `Gamma[1/2 + x]/(-1 + x)`:

```
Plot[ Gamma[1/2 + x]/(-1 + x), {x, 1, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

In order to solve the system we have to determine monotonicity intervals of the function, i.e. where it decreases and increases respectively. We can find the minimum of the function numerically:

```
NMinimize[{Gamma[1/2 + x]/(-1 + x), x > 1}, x]
```

> ```
> {1.28648, {x -> 2.23263}}
> ```

If we are interested in the argument only we can use `FindRoot`:

```
FindRoot[ D[Gamma[1/2 + x]/(-1 + x), x], {x, 2}]
```

> ```
> {x -> 2.23263}
> ```

or we can find a symbolic solution with:

```
Reduce[ D[Gamma[1/2 + x]/(-1 + x), x] == 0 && 100 > x > 1, x, Reals]
```

> ```
>  Reduce::nint: Warning: Reduce used numeric integration to show that 
>  the solution set found is complete. >>
> ```

```
 x == Root[{-1 - PolyGamma[0, 1/2 + #1] + PolyGamma[0, 1/2 + #1] #1 &, 
            2.23263150493249115565238711315}]
```

Having said that you can figure out what the solution of the original question should be. We demonstrate graphically solutions for `n == 5`. Obvoiusly every integer `k > 5` is a solution and there is no integer solution between `1` and the minimum of the function whatever integer `n` is. It will be convenient to use:

```
f = Log[ Gamma[1/2 + #]/(-1 + #)] &;
```

since `Gamma` increases too rapidly.

```
Plot[{f[x], f[5]}, {x, 1, 13.3}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
      Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> {Lighter @ Cyan, Darker @ Orange},
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.017], Point[{#, f[#]}& @ 
                 Root[{-1 - PolyGamma[0, 1/2 + #1] + PolyGamma[0, 1/2 + #1] #1 &, 
                       2.23263150493249115565238711315}]], 
                 Darker @ Green, PointSize[0.019], Point[{#, f[#]} & /@ Range[6, 13]], 
                 Blue, Point[{#, f[#]}& @ 5]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Every integer greater than `n` is a solution to the given inequality in the integers greater than `1`. In the above plot the blue point denotes `{5, f[5]}` while higher integers in green denotes solutions `k > n`.

We encounter similar problems  more often, e.g. see e.g. [When does the real part of Zeta vanish on the critical line?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/when-does-the-real-part-of-zeta-vanish-on-the-critical-line/34607#34607). This post also clarify why another symbolic function (namely `ZetaZero`) was needed for finding symbolic roots of the Riemann Zeta function.  I recommend reading also [Transcendental Roots](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/newin7/content/TranscendentalRoots/) for a general setting of the underlying issue.

Comment: Wonderful treatment of the problem. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I think that [special functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/SpecialFunctions.html) are one of the most impressive achievements of _WRI_.

Comment: Very nicely done. +1

Comment: Many thanks for this really nice treatment of the problem. You are right in the original problem posted abvoe it is pretty easy to see what the solutions for a given n should be. But in cases like $2\frac{\Gamma(-0.5+n)}{\Gamma(n)}=\frac{\Gamma(-0.5+k)}{\Gamma(k)}$ it is not obvious.

Comment: @user11937  I answered the question you had asked, not another one. You can always use e.g. FullSimplify with appropriate assumptions. However since I can't see any clarification I'm curious what you really expect to get  and awaiting more precise formulation of the problem. I really don't like ambiguous questions. One should beware of taking to much time of another users. Nonetheless I'm trying to help and provide the best answers I can.

Answer (score 3):

```
FindInstance[Gamma[1/2 + n]/(-1 + n) < Gamma[1/2 + k]/(-1 + k) && k > 1 && n > 1, {n, k}]
```

gives

```
 {{n -> 42/5, k -> 82/5}}
```

To find more solutions:

```
Table[FindInstance[Gamma[1/2 + n]/(-1 + n) < Gamma[1/2 + k]/(-1 + k) 
  && k > 1 && n > 1, {n, k}, RandomSeed -> i], {i, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way to generate more solutions as Rasher commented below is to use quantity last argument. see example.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me why Reduce does not work?

Comment: Or just `FindInstance[
 Gamma[1/2 + n]/(-1 + n) < Gamma[1/2 + k]/(-1 + k) && k > 1 && 
  n > 1, {n, k}, 20]`, replace `20` with however many instances you want to try to find,,,

Comment: @rasher yes, that is easier. I was looking at RandomSeed -> i as I never used it before. thanks,

Comment: @user11937 I can't answer why Reduce did not solve it. Other than what the message said `cannot be solved by the methods available to Reduce`