# Solve an equation that include Gamma

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I want to solve the following  equation

```
Solve[Gamma[1 + x]/Gamma[x - 1/2] + 1 == 0, x]
```

I have answer x=-0.25, but I can not obtain this answer with Mathematica. Any suggestion?

Comment: No its not, `Gamma[1 + x]/Gamma[x - 1/2] + 1 /. x -> -0.25` gives $0.746508$ not zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Introduction

There should be a duplicate of this question somewhere on this site:

> How does one solve a transcendental equation?

That is basically what this question comes down to.

@Artes has some great answers to this kind of question (see these [search results](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=transcendental+solve+user%3A184)), as do [others](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bequation-solving%5d%20votes%3a10%20is%3aa%20*solve), and his answer to [Solving Inequalities with Gamma Function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41088/solving-inequalities-with-gamma-function/41099#41099) addresses the issue here, although that question is focused on proving an inequality.  The problem in determining whether another question is a duplicate comes down to when niggling details are insignificant and when they distinctive.

Some transcendental equations can be solved outright by [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) and there are some cases where [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) or [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) will succeed where `Solve` fails.  In cases where `Reduce` succeeds, the solutions can be expected to be obtained through `Solve` via the option `Method -> Reduce`.  If all these solvers fail, then one is left with searching for roots with [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) or even [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) functions and [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html).

When the equation is not solved by `Solve` or `NSolve`, one can often find the solutions in given ranges for the variables by including inequalities for the variables in the system of equations.  Sometimes this returns some but not all solutions.  Often a warning message is issued if *Mathematica* could not prove it found all the solutions.  This does not necessarily mean that it missed some, only that it might have missed some.  (I do not know whether the lack of such a warning means it has found all solutions; barring bugs, I would be inclined to think so.)  There are options that can change the effectiveness of solvers.  See this [Chat exchange](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13283749#13283749) about [the following example](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=13284939#13284939).

```
With[{sysopts = SystemOptions["ReduceOptions"]},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> {"IntervalRootsOptions" -> {"MaxFailures" -> 500}}],
  NSolve[Tan[1/x] == x && -1 < x < 1, x],
  SetSystemOptions[sysopts]
  ]]
```

#### OP's example

In the present case, if we add an interval restriction for `x` to `Solve` or `NSolve`, we get the solutions in the interval.  We also get the warning that *Mathematica* could not prove all solutions were found.  (If you look at the graph, it seems highly unlikely that any were missed.)

```
Solve[Gamma[1 + x]/Gamma[x - 1/2] + 1 == 0 && -5 < x < 0, x]
```

> Solve::incs: Warning: Solve was unable to prove that the solution set found is complete. >>

```
{{x -> Root[{Gamma[-(1/2) + #1] + Gamma[1 + #1] &, -4.46893828993129591992496474699}]},
 {x -> Root[{Gamma[-(1/2) + #1] + Gamma[1 + #1] &, -3.45541261687696656217049758405}]},
 {x -> Root[{Gamma[-(1/2) + #1] + Gamma[1 + #1] &, -2.42782741941729578989446499935}]},
 {x -> Root[{Gamma[-(1/2) + #1] + Gamma[1 + #1] &, -1.35003346091660385890507014012}]}}
```

`Solve` yields exact answers, often in the form of [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects as above (see also this answer, [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects/13768#13768)). `NSolve` will return approximate solutions (of [`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision.html) by default):

```
NSolve[Gamma[1 + x]/Gamma[x - 1/2] + 1 == 0 && -5 < x < 0, x]
(*  {{x -> -4.46894}, {x -> -3.45541}, {x -> -2.42783}, {x -> -1.35003}}  *)
```

#### Example where `Solve` fails and `NSolve` succeeds

A slight tweak of the OP's equation cause `Solve` to fail.  (I don't know why.)

```
Solve[Gamma[1 + x]/Gamma[x + 1/2] + 1 == 0 && -2 < x < 0, x]
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

`Reduce` also fails, but `NSolve` succeeds:

```
NSolve[Gamma[1 + x]/Gamma[x + 1/2] + 1 == 0 && -2 < x < 0, x]
(*{{x -> -4.64162}, {x -> -3.65785}, {x -> -2.68115}, {x -> -1.71854}, {x -> -0.791949}}*)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Gamma[1 + x]/Gamma[x - 1/2] + 1 /. x -> -0.25
```

> ```
> 0.746508
> ```

```
Plot[Gamma[1 + x]/Gamma[x - 1/2] + 1, {x, -2, 2}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FindRoot[Gamma[1 + x]/Gamma[x - 1/2] + 1, {x, -1.4}]
```

> {x -> -1.35003}

```
Plot[Gamma[1 + x]/Gamma[x - 1/2] + 1, {x, -2, 2}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{-1.35, 0}]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

```
Solve[Gamma[1 + x]/Gamma[x - 1/2] + 1 == 0 && -10 < x < 0, x, 
Reals] // N // Quiet

 {x -> -9.48952, x -> -8.48767, x -> -7.4852, x -> -6.48176, 
  x -> -5.47676, x -> -4.46894, x -> -3.45541, x -> -2.42783,x -> -1.35003}
```

**NSolve** is **10** times faster **:)**

```
NSolve[Gamma[1 + x]/Gamma[x - 1/2] + 1 == 0 && -10 < x < 0, x, Reals]
```