# Counting Real roots

Tags: equation-solving

I'm interested on how to count the number of real roots of a random polynomials in an instant, how to put the result in a table and how to plot it in a graph.I generated 1 million random polynomials following Gaussian Distribution with mean 0 and variance 1. I used this command

```
r:=GaussianDistribution[0,1]
y=randompol[n_,i_]:=Sum[r x^{j},{j,0,n}]
Solve[y==0,x]
CountRoots[y,x]
```

But the command Countroots does not apply for it says that the above generated random polynomials is not univariate. But it seems awkward that when I manually paste the generated random polynomial to the CountRoots command instead of using link, it works!

But I want to do it in 1 million random polynomials and it is not practical for me to do so. I already used `y//Tableform` and `Remove[{}]` because I thought that the problem is braces since the random polynomials generated using this command `y=randompol[n_,i_]:=Sum[r x^{j},{j,0,n}]` is inside a brace while the `CountRoots` command does not require braces, but i Failed and it did not work.

please help me...

Comment: Your code is very confusing! The definition of r is nonsense, `Solve` unnecessary, your function doesn't produce any polynomials and what is `i`?

Comment: See e.g. this [Count and plot the number of solutions in an interval](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24790/count-and-plot-the-number-of-solutions-in-an-interval/24808#24808).

Comment: Thank You Teake Nutma,, :) it help me a lot :) I'll try your suggestion immediately..tnx a lot :)

Comment: Sir @Teake Nutma...your code works almost perfectly only that the last command do not execute..I lower the range up to 10 examples of 2 degree polynomials but the number of real roots does not appear? thanks a lot :) sorry for disturbance sir

additionally i just want to ask why constant terms are not included in the generations of random polynomials. based on your code the power is restricted only on positive integers.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the constant terms; I've updated the answer to accommodate them. I think the reason why you weren't seeing the number of real roots was the trailing `;` at the end of the lines of code -- I've also removed them. Btw, next time please post comments to answers as comments to those answers, not as a comment of your own question :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. First, `GaussianDistribution` is not a built-in function; I think you want to have [`NormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalDistribution.html) in combination with [`RandomVariate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html).
Secondly, [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) returns `Null` (or `$Failed` if something went wrong), so `y` has the value `Null` after your second line. Hence the lines after that don't work.

Allow me to propose a function that does more or less what you want:

```
RandomPolynomial[degree_Integer?Positive, distribution_:NormalDistribution[]] := 
  With[{functionbody = Sum[RandomVariate @ distribution #^i, {i, 0, degree}]},
    functionbody &
  ];
```

You can then define a random polynomial as follows:

```
randompol = RandomPolynomial[4]
```

> ```
> 1.75688 - 0.0960234 # + 0.762145 #^2 - 2.28435 #^3 + 1.34854 #^4 &
> ```

This is a so-called [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html); you can let it act on e.g. the variable `x` to get a function of `x`:

```
randompol[x]
```

> ```
> 1.75688 - 0.0960234 x + 0.762145 x^2 - 2.28435 x^3 + 1.34854 x^4
> ```

Counting real roots then works straightforwardly:

```
CountRoots[randompol[x], x]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Then, if you want to generate one million random polynomials, you can do:

```
randompolys = Table[RandomPolynomial[4], {10^6}]
```

Finally, the number of real roots can be found by:

```
numrealroots = CountRoots[#[x], x] & /@ randompolys
```

Note that this last command will take some time to compute!

Comment: Sir @Teake Nutma..:) tnx a lot lot.:)

if it doesn't bother you sir,may I ask again a question?Im new in using Mathematica so i Cant form complex commands... Hmm... Since my research involve a very large number of data...May I ask sir how to make a code in such a way that it will form a table, where in the first column is the degree of the polynomial, the second column, composed of all possible number of real roots, the third column composed of frequency for every real root and the last column is for the product of the frequency and the number of real roots. at the right bottom is the average.

Comment: @Jerwin I'd recommend posting that as a new question. Small tip: include an explicit example of what you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[myCount];
SetAttributes[myCount, Listable];

myCount[deg_, quant_] := (CountRoots[#, \[FormalX]] & /@ 
        ((Array[\[FormalX]^# &, deg + 1, 0].#) & /@ 
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {quant, deg + 1}]))

Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
ErrorListPlot[{Mean@#, StandardDeviation@#} & /@ myCount[Range@30, 100], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I can't get this to run; perhaps you (or I) made a copy-paste error somewhere? Also, given the OP's familiarity with Mathematica you might want to explain a bit what's going on.

Comment: @TeakeNutma I pasted an old version. Thanks. Corrected.